# How to create a multi-level option list in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create multi level option list in React using react state and props. I can get this working for 2 levels using 2d arrays in react state but not sure how to make it work at 3 levels.

E.g

```
1st page 

Option 1 , Option 2, Option 3

> if user selects Option 1

2nd Page 

Option 1.a, Option 1.b, Option 1.c 

> if user selects 1.b 

3rd Page 

Final Result of choosing Option 1 & Option 1.b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go for a much simpler approach.

If you know what options need to be. Then make 1 array that is for the first options:

```
const firstPageArray = [Option1, Option2, Option3];
```

then store what is selected in the component state, lets say user has selected Option1. Then use `this.setState({firstPageSelection: Option1});`

Based on what is in that state then you can render the second array:

```
const secondPageArray = [Option1.a, Option1.b, Option1.c];
```

do the same as you did before and based on the option selected set the state of your component to something like `this.setState({secondPageSelection: Option1.a});`

And for your final requirement you can use the 2 states that you have stored to show the message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you suggest I pass the state when I am linking to a new page? I used `params` to pass the first page option down to the second page not sure how I pass both the first page option and second page option to the third page.